I can not stop the observer for livedata inside a fragment using removeObserver
I have a Fragment which is a tab (among a few other tabs) in an activity. In a part of the fragment I want to observe my Livedata of fjViewModel once. This is the code:
public class JInPersonFragment extends Fragment {


    private FJViewModel fjViewModel;

    public static JInPersonFragment newInstance() {return new JInPersonFragment();}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        _InPerson = FragmentJInPersonBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        fjViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get( FJViewModel.class);


        Observer<Filterj> observer = new Observer<Filterj>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Filterj filterj)
            {//the code keeps coming back inside the onChanged() method
                Log.i("jinperson",""+(filterj==null)); 

                 ....

                fjViewModel.getFiltersById(0).removeObserver(this);
            }
        };

        fjViewModel.getFiltersById(0).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), observer);

       return _InPerson.getRoot();
    }


The observer is apparrently not removed with the above code. What am I doing wrong? I only know Java right now and I can not understand answers in Kotlin.
Also here is my ViewModel
public class FJViewModel extends AndroidViewModel
{
    private FJRepository repo;
    private LiveData<List<Filterj>> allFilters;

    public FJViewModel(@NonNull Application application)
    {
        super(application);
        repo = new FJRepository(application);
        allFilters = repo.getAllFilters();
    }

    public void insert(Filterj filter) {
        repo.insert(filter);
    }
    public void update(Filterj filter) {
        repo.update(filter);
    }
    public void delete(Filterj filter) {
        repo.delete(filter);
    }
    public LiveData<List<Filterj>> getAllFilters(){
        return allFilters;
    }
    public LiveData<Filterj> getFiltersById(int id){
        return repo.getFiltersById(id);
    }
}

Strangely, when I use getAllFilters() instead of the getFiltersById(0) in the code, removeObserver works and the observer only runs once. Here is the DAO:
@Dao
public interface FJDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(Filterj filter);
    @Update
    void update(Filterj filter);
    @Delete
    void delete(Filterj filter);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM filter_jalase ORDER BY id ASC")
    LiveData<List<Filterj>> getAllFilters();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM filter_jalase WHERE id = :id")
    LiveData<Filterj> getFiltersById(int id);

}



can you show please  fjViewModel.getFiltersById(0) method?

thanks) did you try to move your viewModel logic from onCreateView to onViewCreated method?

Thanks. Do you mean to move the line fjViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get( FJViewModel.class); to the onViewCreated? I did that but it did not change anything.

did  you fix it? no, i'm talking about the logic where you create observer and subscribe to it.

No still not fixed yet. If I understand correctly I moved the observer and the line after it, i.e. fjViewModel.getFiltersById(0).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), observer);, to the onViewCreated, but that did not work either. As far As I can tell, the problem is that nothing related to getFiltersById is mentioned inside the constructor of the FJViewModel, because 'getAllFilters()is working correctly withremoveObserver`, and that is the only difference between them.

oh bro, sorry, now i see your dao, if you use WHERE "SELECT * FROM filter_jalase WHERE id = :id"  this returns not one object but a list, where will the objects with your id. if there is one object in the database with this id, you will get list with one object, if there are several objects with the same id you will get list with two objects. So change LiveData to LiveData<List>

If you want to get one object, change your query request
@Query("SELECT * FROM filter_jalase WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1")
LiveData getFiltersById(int id);

@Yura In my database there is only one entry with that id (I set the ids by hand), so even when I change the LIMIT to 1, it won't solve the problem. and the observer won't stop.
